# Z80 CPU cross-assembler for the MSX standard

Tags: cross-compilation, assembly

I'm trying to program for the old eighties MSX standard that used a Z80 CPU.

My problem is that I can't seem to find a cross-assembler for this CPU using the MSX standard.

Is there any Z80 CPU MSX standard cross-assembler for Linux?

*P.S: I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 64 bit.*

Comment: Do you mean that you're running Mint on the Z80?  Your question seems to be missing something.  Note that, if that's what you want, Google can find you a cross-compiler for it by searching `z80 cross-compiler linux`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier he is asking for cross-assemblers for the Z80, an ancient 8-bit CPU.

Comment: I used to be interested in the Z80 emulation scene and actually wrote an emulator for the ZX Spectrum many years ago, but alas, not for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Z80 architecture was pretty well known and documented, and had quite an active emulator community. In fact, you still can find a lot of cross-assemblers and related toolchains in Linux distributions.

Have a look at the Debian/Ubuntu packages `binutils-z80`, `crasm`, `d52`, `pasmo`, `z80asm`, and `z80dasm`.

There is also the package [sdcc](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net) that is a C cross-compiler and associated development toolchain capable of outputting Z80 code (among other CPUs).

I found an old page talking about pasmo generating code for the native MSX BLOAD format, and about it being used to write an open source BIOS clone for MSX emulators [here](http://pasmo.speccy.org).

> Pasmo is a Z80 cross assembler, written in standard C++ that compiles
>   easily in multiple platforms. Actually can generate object code in the
>   following formats: raw binary, Intel HEX, PRL for CP/M Plus RSX,
>   Plus3Dos (Spectrum +3 disk), TAP, TZX and CDT (Spectrum and Amstrad
>   CPC emulators tape images), AmsDos (Amstrad CPC disk) and MSX (for use
>   with BLOAD from disk in Basic).
>
> Some open source works written with Pasmo.
>   C-BIOS: A compatible replacement for the MSX BIOS

Comment: I tried ``z80asm``, ``pasmo`` and another I just found called ``asmsx``. For the three of them, I couldn't compile a simple "Hello world" I found in a tutorial (I'm just abou to get started learning assembly, but I need to have the environment set up beforehand). Is there any MSX sample code I could try to compile to see which works the best? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you in specific MSX assembly extensions... my speciality is Z80 raw or ZX Spectrum assembly code. I am young enough not to have gone through CP/M Z80 code, for instance. While I am contrmporary to MSX, it never was a thing here, and the speccy was widely used and cheap

Comment: `atari800` is an 8-bit Atari emulator, so it uses a 6502 emulator. I don't think it would be much use to someone interested in MSX on Z80s ;-).

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Kitt, took it out. I actually was in doubt too. The Z80 is 8-bit too.

Comment: Indeed! Check out [Retrocomputing SE](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), you'll probably find it interesting (assuming you don't know about it already).

Comment: @StephenKitt Not much active there....I was much more active in the Z80 scene in the 90s, when I wrote my thesis, and wrote one of the first emulators for Windows, and the first Windows emulator for the ZX Spectrum. Come to think of it, I might upload it to my github. I still have a fondness for that theme, have here in my Mac the pdp7 - pdp11 emulators with Unix 7 and Unix System V.